# Editing page html using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I need help in getting the html of a page, finding a div and adding some html content.
I am not getting the exact and recommended way to do this.

I tried something.

> Adding a content script which run_at: document_start

What it do is simply append the div after body tag and get a html page content from extension files which I need to show.

```
$(function () {
    var style = 'border: 0 none transparent !important; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);';
    var frame = ' <div id="con-1-frame" style="' + style + '">\n\
                </div>';
    $("body").after(frame);
    $("#con-1-frame").load(chrome.extension.getURL("design.html"));
});
```

What is the best way to  achieve this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Explain in detail whats not working in your approach

Comment: I am not a jquery expert so I am playing for my assignment. I need to find a html div and edit it and add some of my content. What I have done is added a div after body tag, but I am not that expert to find a div and alter it using the perfect/recommended way.

Comment: You still havent detailed whats being asked

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work if you run it as a content script.  You need to declare it in your manifest.json file, something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
     {
         "matches": [
             "<all_urls>"
         ],
         "js": ["contentscript.js"]
     }
],
```

This would get added to your manifest.json and assumes:

1. You want this to run on every page - if not, you need to change the matches section.
2. The name of your content script is contentscript.js.

For more information, try looking at these resources:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

If this doesn't solve your problem, I'd try sharing your project structure and the contents of your manifest to get better answers.